# WOT API need help in understanding.

Tags: xml, json, api, url

I don't really understand API myself, but I've come to you guys to try and help me suss this out.

http://www.mywot.com/wiki/API#Reputations That's the api I'm trying to follow.

**What am I aiming for?**

On my website I am parsing all external URL's to see if they are safe, so I am going to use the MYWOT api which will return values depending on the sites safety and reputation reviews.

The links are sent to this file `parse_link.php?url=example.com` So the variable of the url will be `$website = $_GET['url'];`

I'm not asking you to completely code this for me, just some help to help me get my head around this confusing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "safe-checking script" you will need to call the api server with a domain as a value. As per the site you linked to (you should read it!), you want to call it with something like this:

> http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json?hosts=google.com/

(you need a slash after every domain, you can string multiple domains together separated by /)
Your php code will look something like this (this is untested pseudo-code ONLY, don't except it to work!)

```
<?php
$api = 'http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json?hosts=';
$domain = 'google.com.';
$results = file_get_contents($api . $domain);//call to api server
$results = json_decode($results);//turn json in to a php object
//now you can do something based on the results
?>
```

Comment: I thank you so much much, but I really don't understand what I can do with the results? I know I could use the if() {} statement to do something depending on a value. Could you give me just one example?

Comment: Well, what are you tying to do with the results?

Comment: If the URL scored unsatisfactory or below I want to display an alert to the user. http://www.frankmeacey.com/images/ox9nnw.png

Comment: You can echo javascript like echo `'alert("some message")';`

Comment: But what would be the if statement?

Comment: depends on your needs. Your not really asking for someone else to do your work, right? Right?

Comment: I'm not. I just seriously don't understand this. would it be `if ($results >85) { alert ("Bad Site ")}` ?

Comment: @Frank what do you want it to be? At least in English - what are we checking for?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6297/discussion-between-mbrevda-and-frank)